# Rails model attribute showing as symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails model called ExpenseRatio. I am trying to access a specific record in the model, and the value for its field called calculated_expense_ratio (this is a decimal in the database).

```
    xr = ExpenseRatio.find(xr_id)

    @po = MyAPI.ViewPO(po_id)

    items = Array.new
    @po["PurchaseOrderLineItems"].each do |lip|
        lip.each do |li|
            if li["id"].to_i > 0
                new_price = xr.calculated_expense_ratio * li["price"]
                items.push([id: li["id"].to_i,iprice: li["price"], xrid: xr_id, price: new_price,xrv: xr.calculated_expense_ratio])
            end
        end
    end
```

This is all code within an external module in the lib folder. The xr.calculated_expense_ratio does not output the actual decimal value in the record, but rather what looks like a full on symbol similar to this:

```
#<BigDecimal:7f9883d1cd38,'0.42E1',18(45)>
```

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a symbol, it's a `BigDecimal` object.  I'm guessing you are using MySQL as your database and your column is of type `DECIMAL`.  `BigDecimal` is a ruby object similar to `float` but allows for greater precision.  See the following:

http://makandracards.com/makandra/1178-bigdecimal-arithmetic-in-ruby

Comment: Thank you. But how can I make it show the value of the BigDecimal object? I don't seem to have this problem with any of my other attributes...

Comment: Try the `to_s` method: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s